# How to convert this dictionary into a list of tuples?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary

I have this dictionary;

```
Dict={1: ('John', 129L, 37L), 2: ('James', 231L, 23L)}
```

I want to convert it into a list of tuples that look like this;

```
List=[(1, 'John', 129L, 37L), (2, 'James', 231L, 23L)]
```

I tried Dict.items() but it did not yield the desirable results but was close. What is the correct solution?

I am using Python 2.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
my_dict = {1: ('John', 129L, 37L), 2: ('James', 231L, 23L)} 
print [(k,) + my_dict[k] for k in my_dict]
# [(1, 'John', 129L, 37L), (2, 'James', 231L, 23L)]
```

Sorted by keys version:

```
print [(k,) + my_dict[k] for k in sorted(my_dict)]
```

**Explanation:**

`(k,) + my_dict[k]` is extending the tuple `(k,)` (Yes, a single item, with comma, inside parens is a tuple) by concatenating with the values corresponding to the key `k`

Answer (score 3):

Using [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> d = {1: ('John', 129L, 37L), 2: ('James', 231L, 23L)}
>>> [(key,) + value for key, value in d.iteritems()]
[(1, 'John', 129L, 37L), (2, 'James', 231L, 23L)]
```

BTW, the order of items in the generated list is not guaranteed. Because `dict` is a unordered mapping.

If you want the result to be ordered by keys, use `sorted`:

```
>>> [(key,) + value for key, value in sorted(d.iteritems())]
[(1, 'John', 129L, 37L), (2, 'James', 231L, 23L)]
```

Comment: It is quite likely that the OP wants the list sorted by key.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! But your response speed makes me feel stupid:)

Comment: @user2357112, Thank you for comment. I updated the answer to include another version that sort items by key.

Answer (score 0):

Using map:

```
map(lambda x: (x,) + Dict[x] , Dict.keys())
```

Output:

```
[(1, 'John', 129L, 37L), (2, 'James', 231L, 23L)]
```

Comment: `.keys()` is redundant.

Comment: @user3 `.keys()` has to create a list, so it has performance issue as well.

Comment: @thefourtheye, agree.